# Temporary password expiration with AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I just changed the setting for how quickly temporary passwords expire on my Congito user pool. The documentation is not clear about whether or not that change is applied to users who have already been sent temporary passwords.

I currently have a number of users who have been invited with temporary passwords when that setting was for a 7 day expiration period. Now that I changed that setting to 14 days, do you know if those passwords will now last 14 days?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, changing the temporary password validity period is not retroactive.

Example: your validity period is 24 hours. You send an invitation to a user who doesn't use their temporary password within 24 hours. After 48 hours, you change the validity period to 72 hours. But the temporary password has already expired. So when at 50 hours the user tries to sign in, they will not be able to.

**Update:** As pointed out by @Asoc in the comments, this applies even if the user's password hasn't yet expired. It seems that the password expiration date is set at user creation time and cannot be modified by changing the policy.

Comment: How about if the temporary password has not yet expired? e.g Validity period is 24 hours. You send an invitation to a user and after 12 hours you change the validity period to 72 hours?

Comment: That's a good question, I don't know the answer. Can you test it and report back?

Comment: Tested. Can confirm the change is not retroactively applied even if the temp password has not yet expired.

Comment: Is there any way to get to know when a user's temporary password expires?

Comment: You can use [`AdminGetUser`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminGetUser.html) and friends and then examine the `UserCreateDate`. If you add the `TemporaryPasswordValidityDays` to this datetime, you'll get the end of temporary password period. However, this would only work for new users.